# Cannot convert pixel coordinate to world coordinate

Tags: python

I try convert pixel coordinate to world coordinate. When I have intrinsic matrix, rotation vector, and translation vector

```
intrinsicMatrix = np.array([[3442.02,0,1286.04],
                        [0,3444.89,1009.09],
                        [0,0,1]])
traslationVector = np.array([[-53.47360],[-40.4999],[744.253]])
rotationVector = np.array([ 0.00707434,0.00232072,0.022695])
rotationMatrix = cv2.Rodrigues(R)[0]
extrinsMatric = [rotationMatrix | traslationVector ]
```

I use

```
pixelCoords = intrinsicMatrix * extrinsicMatric * worldCoords
```

to calculate worldCoords. But when

```
pixelCoords = [0,0,1], worldCoords  =[  55.66394942 ,  33.7139661  ,-743.38827207]
```

and

```
pixelCoords = [2000,2000,1], worldCoords [  56.25803192  , 34.28119113 ,-743.39096856]
```

`worldCoords` does not change.

What is my problem?

Comment: Please show us an executable example.  Nowhere in that code are you computing `worldCoords`, so we can't tell where you are going wrong.  Which things are inputs, which things are outputs?

Comment: my input: intrinsicMatrix, rotationVector, translationVector,pixelCoord,
 and output is worldCoords

Comment: @TimRoberts I follow this to caculate world coordiates


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryarz.jpg

Comment: That image converts FROM world coordinates TO pixel coordinates.

Comment: Because of confidentiality of my company, so i cant show image. But I have parameter of camera: Fx =3442.02, Fy = 3444.89, Cx = 1286.04, Cy = 1009.09, Translation vector = -53.47360,-40.4999,744.253, Rotation vector = 0.00707434,0.00232072,0.022695

Comment: You show: `"pixelCoords = intrinsicMatrix * extrinsicMatric * worldCoords`". But you say: `"my input: intrinsicMatrix, rotationVector, translationVector,pixelCoord, and output is worldCoords`".  Your code seems to contradict your statement.  Isn't `pixelCoords` your output?

Comment: @CryptoFool I'm sorry. i follow "pixelCoords = intrinsicMatrix * extrinsicMatric * worldCoords" to caculate worldCoords

Comment: NO, YOU DON'T!  That's the point we're ALL trying to make.  In that statement, `worldCoords` is an INPUT.  It is not an OUTPUT.  The output is `pixelCoords`.  Please clarify.

Comment: There is no way to go FROM `pixelCoords` to `worldCoords`.  The transform is not one-to-one.  There are many world coordinates that map to each pixel coordinate.